# Is there any way to see the detailed memory map during debugging python on vscode?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, memory

I knew there is a function to check how values in memory change when I program C language on Visual Studio. However, I wonder if there is the way to check memory map on vscode while python programming or not. please tell me the existence. thank you in advance.

Comment: python uses garbage collection so a memory view would not be useful, the debugger shows you all the local and global variables, what more do you want